# Ruby: require downloaded gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have finished writing a ruby script which I would like to share with others, but I am having trouble getting the user to install the necessary gems. I have tried 2 approaches, and a fix for either of them would be greatly appreciated! I require the following gems:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'
require 'mechanize'
```

I have tried the following:

1) Generate a stand-alone app with Platypus. I created the Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "highline", "~> 1.6.20"
gem "mechanize", "~> 2.7.3"
```

and bundle installed it and included require 'bundler/setup'. I uploaded Gemfile.lock and the ruby script but I receive this error when I run it:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- highline/import (LoadError)
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`require'
>       from /Users/jonathanli/Documents/CS_projects/iSites/Isites.app/Contents/Resources/script:5:in `'

2) I downloaded the gem files and placed them directly in my host folder. I am unsure of how to modify my require statements, but it is not working as it stands right now.

Thanks in advance everyone! Hope this was enough detail.

Comment: Have you tried deployment mode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300613/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-install-deployment-and-bundle-pack

I've had this issue with obviously installed gems, which needed to be used in deployment mode for *magically mysterious* reasons. Not really an answer, but often a workaround.

Comment: With a bundler - you need to upload `Gemfile`, not `Gemfile.lock` and make them to run `bundle install` - this will install all required gems and generate `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: BroiStatse-So do I have to run bundle install inside the script? I have already done it in Terminal to get Gemfile.lock

Comment: “I have finished writing a ruby script which I would like to share with others” – it might be easiest if you create your own Gem. Then you will be able to declare your dependencies in your Gem’s specification and they will be fetched by your users automatically. Have a look at http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/