# Ruby on Rails: Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run 'bundle install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, fedena

I am trying to run Fedena which is Ruby on Rails application. I have a hosting account with CPanel. When I try to run Ruby on Rails application, I see the following error in logs:

```
Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run 'bundle install'
```

Questions:

1. Is this issue related to Ruby on Rails version? How do I know which version I am running?
2. How do I fix this issue?

Here's complete error:

```
/home/abc/rails_apps/abc/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:18: Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run `bundle install`? (RuntimeError)
    from /home/abc/rails_apps/abc/config/boot.rb:29:in `load'
    from /home/abc/rails_apps/abc/config/boot.rb:29:in `preinitialize'
    from /home/abc/rails_apps/abc/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
    from /home/abc/rails_apps/abc/config/boot.rb:127
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/abc/rails_apps/abc/config/environment.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in `rails'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:23:in `load'
```

Comment: as it asks... is the bundle install successful, what is the rails and ruby version

Comment: did you try running bundle install?

Comment: How to run bundle install? I have never used Ruby on Rails application before.

Answer (score 0):

I run `fedena` app in local m/c

1. [image: versions]
2. [bundle install info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300613/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-install-deployment-and-bundle-pack)

Hope it helps..

Comment: How do I install bundle on CPanel?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are deploying in Cpanel.
First, you should get SSH access then you can run command `bundle install` in the root folder on the app.

1. You can run `rails -v` via SSH to know about the Rails version.
2. Run command `bundle install` in the root folder on the app to fix this issue.