# Is it possible to cache gems using rvm and bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rubygems, rvm, bundler

We have many gems in several rails projects.  We use rvm and bundler and rubygems and gemsets.  Is there a way to locally cache the gems that I need instead of having bundler ask gem to go get them?  We change the gem name each time we have a new major branch...  My system has many copies of many of the gems I am downloading.  I have tried using a proxy, but that does not seem any faster, and requires running the vm and sometimes I have to manually flush the cache because it gets mixed up about what is available.

Comment: I don't know if this would work with gemsets but you could try `bundle install --local`, it tells bundler to skip connection with `rubygems.org` idk if it would try copying gems from other gemsets or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` in development mode 
to set your gems in vendor folder, and `bundle package` to grab the gems and packages them in vendor/cache. Read more about [bundle package](http://bundler.io/bundle_package.html).

Read this [question, and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300613/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-install-deployment-and-bundle-pack), I hope it'll be helpful for you.

Comment: I guess you are talking about deployment issues?  That's not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler does not currently use a shared, local cache, but you might have better luck by *not* using gemsets.

By default, Bundler installs gems to a shared location, and if you use the same shared location for all of your projects, it will reuse the same installed gems for any projects that use the same version of those gems (assuming that they use the same version of Ruby, too).

The isolation provided by gemsets is largely unnecessary with Bundler, which sets up load paths correctly so that only the correct version of each gem is visible to the application.