# redirect_to after AJAX post stops working on remote machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

I have a "create" action, that gets called by AJAX. This then redirects to another action. On my local machine, everything works fine. Here are the log files from my local machine:

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-06 20:08:44 +0200
Processing by TasksController#create as JS

Started GET "/roles/refresh_blank_page?cursor=3988&focus=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-06 20:08:44 +0200
Processing by RolesController#refresh_blank_page as JS
```

But on the remote machine, in development or production, it breaks with "ActionController::UnknownFormat". The format suddenly seems to be HTML, as you can see in the log:

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 88.217.180.75 at 2016-10-06 20:13:00 +0200
Processing by TasksController#create as JS

Started GET "/roles/refresh_blank_page?cursor=3981&focus=true" for 88.217.180.75 at 2016-10-06 20:13:02 +0200
Processing by RolesController#refresh_blank_page as HTML
```

Here are my actions:

```
def create
  (...)
  redirect_to roles_refresh_blank_page_path(focus: true, cursor: @task.id)
end


def refresh_blank_page
  (...)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :file => "/roles/refresh_blank_page.js.erb" }
  end
end
```

I read many posts here and added "format: 'js'" to the redirect (also tried "remote:true")

```
redirect_to roles_refresh_blank_page_path(focus: true, cursor: @task.id, format:'js')
```

In the log I see now:

```
Started GET "/roles/refresh_blank_page.js?cursor=3983&focus=true" for 88.217.180.75 at 2016-10-06 20:19:12 +0200
Processing by RolesController#refresh_blank_page as JS
```

But this now produces "ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest in RolesController#refresh_blank_page"

I compared the gems on my local machine and on the remote machine. Some of the gems on the remote machine have higher version numbers. In both cases I'm running rails 4.1.8 and ruby 2.1.5p273.

Thanks for any help,
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by packaging all my development gems into vendor/cache, using `bundle package`. Now it works on the remote machine.

cf. [Whats the difference between bundle install --deployment and bundle pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300613/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-install-deployment-and-bundle-pack)